# Django: select_related and GenericRelation

Tags: django, django-orm

Does select_related work for GenericRelation relations, or is there a reasonable alternative? At the moment Django's doing individual sql calls for each item in my queryset, and I'd like to avoid that using something like select_related.

```
class Claim(models.Model):
    proof = generic.GenericRelation(Proof)


class Proof(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

I'm selecting a bunch of Claims, and I'd like the related Proofs to be pulled in instead of queried individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like [select_related and GRs don't work together](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2820).  I guess you could write some kind of accessor for Claim that gets them all via the same query. This [post gives you some pointers](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/generating-aggregate-data-across-generic-relations/) on raw SQL to get generic objects, if you need them

Answer (score 19):

There isn't a built-in way to do this. But I've posted a technique for simulating `select_related` on generic relations [on my blog](http://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/02/22/django-patterns-part-4-forwards-generic-relations/).

---

Blog content summarized:

We can use Django's `_content_object_cache` field to essentially create our own `select_related` for generic relations.

```
generics = {}
for item in queryset:
    generics.setdefault(item.content_type_id, set()).add(item.object_id)

content_types = ContentType.objects.in_bulk(generics.keys())

relations = {}
for ct, fk_list in generics.items():
    ct_model = content_types[ct].model_class()
    relations[ct] = ct_model.objects.in_bulk(list(fk_list))

for item in queryset:
    setattr(item, '_content_object_cache', 
            relations[item.content_type_id][item.object_id])
```

> Here we get all the different content types used by the relationships
>   in the queryset, and the set of distinct object IDs for each one, then
>   use the built-in in_bulk manager method to get all the content types
>   at once in a nice ready-to-use dictionary keyed by ID. Then, we do one
>   query per content type, again using in_bulk, to get all the actual
>   object.
>
> Finally, we simply set the relevant object to the
>   _content_object_cache field of the source item. The reason we do this is that this is the attribute that Django would check, and populate if
>   necessary, if you called x.content_object directly. By pre-populating
>   it, we're ensuring that Django will never need to call the individual
>   lookup - in effect what we're doing is implementing a kind of
>   select_related() for generic relations.

Answer (score 3):

you can use .extra() function to manually extract fields :

```
Claims.filter(proof__filteryouwant=valueyouwant).extra(select={'field_to_pull':'proof_proof.field_to_pull'})
```

The .filter() will do the join, the .extra() will pull a field.
proof_proof is the SQL table name for Proof model.
If you need more than one field, specify each of them in the dictionnary.