# MySQL database being hit too many times with django query

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm using django-favorites to pull the list of objects faved by a user.  The app has a model and a manager

```
class FavoriteManager(models.Manager):
    """ A Manager for Favorites
    """
    def favorites_for_user(self, user):
        """ Returns Favorites for a specific user
        """
        return self.get_query_set().filter(user=user)

class Favorite(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = FavoriteManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('favorite')
        verbose_name_plural = _('favorites')
        unique_together = (('user', 'content_type', 'object_id'),)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s added %s as a favorite" % (self.user, self.content_object)
```

In my view, I'm pulling the faves for a user

```
 from favorites.models import Favorite
 def myfavorites(request):

      item = Favorite.objects.favorites_for_user(user=request.user)

      return render_to_response('myfavorites.html', {
           'favorites':item
      },
      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In my template, I try to get a list of the favorites and their model types:

```
{% for fave in favorites %}
    {{ fave.content_type }}<br>
    {{ fave.content_object }}<br><br>
{% endfor %}
```

But using the django debug toolbar, I see that I'm hitting the database twice for each loop.  The code is querying the database for the content_type and the content_object for every fave in the favorites object.

**How do I optimize the code so that the data is pulled one time without need for several hits to the database to retrieve information?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can decide between several solutions:

1. **Generic relation pre-fetching**, you can use [this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1079/) like this [example app](https://github.com/justquick/django-activity-stream/blob/master/actstream/gfk.py).
2. **Identity map/caching**, use the content type and object id to make the key to cache the model, here is [an example](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-social/blob/master/social/notification.py#L317) you can take the code inside `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` and make a template tag, this is the fastest solution you can find
3. **Fetching relations directly**, at some point you will probably need one of the solutions detailed in this [article about generic relation performance](http://oldblog.yourlabs.org/blog/2011/01/27/django-generic-relations-and-performances-solutions/) later when you work with foreign keys.
4. **Use JonhyCache**, [JohnyCache](http://packages.python.org/johnny-cache/) is a caching framework for querysets which works with the django caching abstraction. I did not personally try it yet, as the three solutions were sufficient in my projects.
5. **Cache the template fragment**, less hacky, it looks like [official way to deal with this kind of issue](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching) that spawns a lot of queries, and when the user changes his favorites you could [invalidate the cached version](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1593/).

Note that **select_related() doesn't work on generic relations**. This is because the related object can be in *any* table so it's impossible to make proper joins in pure sql. Generic relations are a feature from Django, not from MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related) queryset method.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
item = Favorite.objects.favorites_for_user(user=request.user).select_related('content_type', 'content_object')
```

EDIT: jpic has rightly pointed out that select_related won't work for 'content_object' because it's a generic foreign key. Unfortunately there's no nice built in way to handle this, and there won't be until Django 1.4 rolls around. In the meantime, check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939552/django-select-related-and-genericrelation) for some pointers. jpic has also posted some good solutions in his answer.