# Query proformance on GenericForeignKey Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have optimized the query below the best I can.

```
 message = Message.objects.defer('gateway', 'batch', 'content_type', 'sender',
                                            'reply_callback')\
                .select_related().get(pk=message_id)
```

However, the model has a field called `billee` (see below)

```
billee = generic.GenericForeignKey()
```

I don't seem to be able to use select_related or defer on this field, maybe because its a GenericForeignKey. Can someone explain why and then give me an example of how to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django: select\_related and GenericRelation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939552/django-select-related-and-genericrelation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select_related()` can't prefetch generic relations (it works only with `ForeignKey` and `OneToOneField`), so You may need to write a raw SQL query if You really want to reduce this one additional query.

In case of fetching many messages at once You may use `prefetch_related()` which can follow generic relations (but still makes an additional query).