# Django query caching through a ForeignKey on a GenericRelation

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-generic-relations

Using a `GenericRelation` to map `Record`s to `Person`s, I have the following code, which works correctly, but there is a performance problem I am trying to address:

**models.py**

```
class RecordX(Record):  # Child class
    ....

class Record(models.Model):  # Parent class
    people = GenericRelation(PersonRecordMapping)

    def people_all(self):
        # Use select_related here to minimize the # of queries later
        return self.people.select_related('person').all()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class PersonRecordMapping(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

class Person(models.Model):
    ...
```

In summary I have:

```
RecordX ===GenericRelation===> PersonRecordMapping ===ForeignKey===> Person
```

The display logic in my application follows these relationships to display all the `Person`s mapped to each `RecordX`:

**views.py**

```
@rendered_with('template.html')
def show_all_recordXs(request):
    recordXs = RecordX.objects.all()
    return { 'recordXs': recordXs }
```

The problem comes in the template:

**template.html**

```
{% for recordX in recordXs %}
    {# Display RecordX's other fields here #}
    <ul>
    {% for map in record.people_all %}{# <=== This generates a query every time! #}
        <li>{{ map.person.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

As indicated, every time I request the `Person`s related to the `RecordX`, it generates a new query.  I cannot seem to figure out how prefetch these initially to avoid the redundant queries.

If I try `selected_related`, I get an error that no `selected_related` fields are possible here (error message: `Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'xxx'. Choices are: (none)`).  Not surprising, I now see -- there aren't any FKs on this model.

If I try `prefetch_related('people')`, no error is thrown, but I still get the same repeated queries on every loop in the template as before.  Likewise for `prefetch_related('people__person')`.  If I try `prefetch_related('personrecordmapping')`, I get an error.

Along the lines of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2943128/1149759), I considered doing trying to simulate a `select_related` via something like:

```
PersonRecordMapping.objects.filter(object_id__in=RecordX.objects.values_list('id', flat=True))
```

but I don't understand the `_content_object_cache` well enough to adapt this answer to my situation (if even the right approach).

So -- how can I pre-fetch all the `Person`s to the `RecordX`s to avoid *n* queries when the page will display *n* `RecordX` objects?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ack, apparently I needed to call *both* -- `prefetch_related('people', 'people__person')`.  SIGH.